# Source NATing Fortigate typical scenario

Tags: nat, fortigate, fortinet, snat, dnat

[image]

I have a small query with respect to NATing in Fortigate.I'm struck in particular by a scenario where the remote network allows users with a specific IP range with a specific port for RDP over a different set of physical links.

User(192.168.60.0/24) in LAN should connect to 10.48.1.3 on remote network which is connected to Internal ports on Fortigate (Nor WAN since it is used for internet).

Link between Remote network firewall & Fortigate has been established (10.189.254.17-10.189.254.18). I can ping remote firewall interace 10.189.254.17.

Admin wants us to access 10.48.1.3 over 3389 port via 10.189.1.8-10.189.1.15 (allowed IPs on remote firewall).

So basically, user (ex:Source: 192.168.60.15 need to access Destination 10.48.1.4 via allowed IPs (10.189.1.8-10.189.1.15) over physical link between Fortigate & remote firewall (10.189.254.18-18.189.254.17).

I have tried VIP (Static NAT) (Source NAT) port forwarding, IP Pool (Destination NAT), but no help.

Please advice how to proceed. It is a typical scenario , can we achieve it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Under your Policy Rule to allow access from 192.168.60.15 to 10.48.1.4.

Simply select NAT then create a Pool and put IP range of 10.189.1.8-10.189.1.15.

Key thing for this to work is you have route on your fortigate pointing 10.48.1.4 to 10.189.254.17 and finally 10.189.254.17 knows 10.189.1.8-10.189.1.15 lives back via 10.189.254.18.

Thats a pretty standard rule and sounds achievable. Some packet captures may help you to debug the issue.

Comment: Hi Smith ,When using IP pools for NATing, there is a limitation that must be taken into account when configuring the pool. If the IP address(es) within the pool are different from the IP address(es) that are assigned to the interface communications based on those IP addresses will fail. For example if the IP addresses assigned to an interface are 172.16.100.1 -172.16.100.14, you cannot choose 10.11.12.50 - 10.11.12.59 for the IP pool.

Comment: http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20Help/objects.067.10.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes I understand your scenario and your requirement ..to access resources on remote firewall on port RDP ie 3389 from fortigate 200d connected switch lan users

**For your requirement no natting required**.
.
*Please configure static route in fortigate 200D as below*

`Ip route 10.48.1.0 255.255.255.0 points towards gateway 10.189.254.17`

And for reverse traffic static route in remote n
/W firewall
`Ip route 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0 pointing towards gateway 10.189.254.18`

And have a security policies in firewalls allowing traffic

**Policy in fortigate 200D**

`Source interface : interface Port need to mention Destination interface : interface Port need to mention Source address :192.168.60.15/32 Destination address :10.48.1.4/32 Port :tcp-3389 Action : allow Security profiles : on`

**Now security policy in remote n/w firewall**

`Source interface : egress interfàe of firewall Destination interface :ingress interface of firewall Source address : 192.168.60.15/32 Destination address :10.48.1.4/32 Port :3389/TCP Action : allowed Security profiles :on`
.

Now user of fortigate 200D lan users can access internal hosted server on remote network firewall on port 3389

For futher security if you wants to hide your ips then you can use source natting in  fortigate 200D firewalls but to accomplish this you need to configure static route in fortigate 200d with destination as source nat pool pointing.
Towards gateway 192.189.254.17..likewise..

Comment: The RDP user needs to appear as 10.189.1.8-10.189.1.15 which does require source NAT.